# Listview onItemClick() checkable

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Im having a listview with items in a custom relativelayout which implements Checkable. It contains a checkbox which gets checked/uncheked via the checkable interface.

setFocusable is set to false for the Checkbox, so that I can use onItemClicked for the listview.

Now when an item is clicked the checkbox is also selected. I am getting crazy about this.

In the getView Method for my Adapter I assign an onCheckChangeListener to the checkbox.

This listener is called everytime a listitem is clicked and checks the Checkbox.

I saw questions how to select a checkable listitem onitemclick, and im getting this behaviour by default....

The Problem with this behaviour is:

The checkbox should get checked by clicking the checkbox not clicking the listitem. I start an Actionmode for the current visible Fragment when a checkbox is clicked, and i replace the current fragment when a listitem is clicked. BOTH is happening right now and that means, wrong Actionmode for wrong fragment and force close on backpress...

best regards vino

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve here, what is your problem/question?

Comment: The checkbox should get checked by clicking the checkbox not clicking the listitem. I start an Actionmode for the current visible Fragment when a checkbox is clicked, and i replace the current fragment when a listitem is clicked. BOTH is happening right now and that means, wrong Actionmode for wrong fragment and fc on backpress.... yeehaaaaaww....

Answer (score 0):

**I think you have to make all other item in custom listview to** setFocusable="false"